# Spring boot read logs

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Java11 Spring Boot application, and an old Java8 Struts1 application.

Is it possible for the Struts1 application to read the console output logs generated by the Spring Boot application?

(I think the answer is it is not possible, but hoping there may be a way)

Comment: This was a first time I've seen this. Fitting question is; why? To correlate or respond on something has happened? I guess you could always just use logfile and then read from that one, or something like that instead of relying on the console.out logger. You could also perhaps just use an open socket or whatever to send a http request whenever something happens - if you're just listening for something to happen, that is. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @vegaasen. I have a SpringBoot service, that does not have a UI.  I do have  a Struts app with a UI, that calls async endpoints on the SpringBoot app. So, I want to be able to show the status of the calls. (It does show the status i.e. inProgress, complete, etc with callbacks, but the logs will provide more details. It would be a nice to have, and if it is not too difficult I want to add it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, your Spring Boot application may use a FileAppender to print to a file.log and your Struts application may read from that file.log.

However, this looks like a quick and dirty solution. Actually, the standard way to allows communication between Java applications is exchanging messages with JMS API.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks you should use something to keep logs that generated by struct and then read them with spring, if you want to read them in real time apache Kafka is my suggestion. stream logs into Kafka with struct then read them in your spring application

Comment: thanks for your answer. What is "sth"?  ("I thinks you should use sth to keep logs...")

Comment: I mean "sth" some thing between struct and spring , it can be file or apache Kafka

Answer (score 1):

when a logger object prints to console, it is writing to System.out.

System.out is a static object of class PrintStream, which is an OutputStream.
And you cannot read from an OutputStream.

Comment: The two apps clearly run in different JVMs. You can easily pipe the output of one application to the input of the other one.

Comment: Two web applications cannot communicate between them. This is against all designs

Comment: Given, that using the standard input/standard output for inter-application communication is rather a poor choice, web application **do** communicate (in the OP's example through an HTTP API).